# Mocked rest template exchange method returning null

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am trying to mock an exchange call from a rest template but for some reason i am getting a null response from the call rather than the response entity i have specified in my test. Note - before adding the injectMocks on my service interface the rest template was trying to make an actual call, when i added that in it makes a mock call but with a null result.

```
@ActiveProfiles("unit-test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Category({ UnitTests.class })
@SpringBootTest@Import({PropertiesTestConfiguration.class})
public class MyTest {

    @Mock
    OAuth2RestTemplate serviceRestTemplate;

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    ServiceInterface serviceInterface;
    
    @Test
    public void getServiceResponse_Success() {

        ResponseEntity<String> mockResponseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>(mockResponseBody, HttpStatus.OK);

        String url = "https://unit_test_/XXX";
        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url);

        Mockito.when(serviceRestTemplate.exchange(    Matchers.anyObject(),     Matchers.any(HttpMethod.class),    Matchers.<HttpEntity> any(),     Matchers.<Class<String>> any()) ).thenReturn(mockResponseEntity);

        ServiceInterface.getClaimByClaimId(XXX);
    }

}
```

In the method I am testing this returns null

```
responseEntity = serviceRestTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder.toUriString(),
        method, requestEntity, String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html) matchers i will recommed to use `is` and `isA` methods to match the value or instance, this artical explains more about [core matchers](https://www.baeldung.com/hamcrest-core-matchers)

```
 Mockito.when(serviceRestTemplate.exchange(is(instanceOf(String.class)),     
                       is(HttpMethod.GET),    
                       is(HttpEntity.class),  
                       isA(String.class)))
                      .thenReturn(mockResponseEntity);
```